# PHPMailer will only send emails from localhost and won't send from server

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, html-email, attachment

I have written a basic script to send an email using PHPMailer.

When I run my script locally to send the email to myself it works fine but when I try to run it from the server, I don't get an email. I want to send emails without specifying SMTP in PHPMailer.

The PHPMailer library is in the codebase directory which is in the same directory as the code below. Also the same on the server.

Here is my PHP code:

```
$to     = 'aaqib.farooq@example.co.uk';
$toName = 'Aaqib Farooq'

require_once('codebase/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer;
$mail->From       = "fromname@example.co.uk";
$mail->FromName   = "Joe Bloggs";
$mail->addAddress($to, $toName);
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject    = "Subject Text";
$mail->Body       = "<p>Lorem ipsum blah blah blah. This is my messsage.</p>";
$mail->AltBody    = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

if ( !$mail->send() ){
    echo 'Email not sent';
} else {
    echo 'Email was sent successfully';
}
```

I've already checked stackoverflow for answers but couldn't find what I need. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you get an error message? And why do you not want to specify SMTP credentials?

Comment: I'm not sure what my SMTP settings are. Are these settings required to run from a server?

Comment: SMTP is more reliable that relying on PHP's mail function. Why don't you use another server, like your Gmail account? Or use Mandrill, Mailgun, Amazon SES, SendGrid, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Add this fileds:

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'host of mail';
$mail->Port = 465 or 587; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'username - usually some@mail';
$mail->Password = 'password';
```

Possible you will need also such settings:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = '';
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->smtpConnect(
    array(
        "ssl" => array(
            "verify_peer" => false,
            "verify_peer_name" => false,
            "allow_self_signed" => true
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Jeez. I've been trying to solve this issue since yesterday. Turns out it was working all along but was going to my junk.